# Empty Blank and Grid Apps from VS2012 Javascript templates fail WACK Performance Test

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs, app-certification-kit

I have tried running WACK 2.2 on 3 different machines (with i5 process, 4-8 GB RAM, SSD/rotational disk) for each of these apps. On each of them these apps failed with app launch times varying anywhere between 5 to 11 seconds.

For example on Machine 1, the app launch performance test failed with following info:

```
Error Found: The performance launch test collected the following results:.?App Launch Time: 11.195 Seconds. Launch times more than 5.0 Seconds will fail on low end systems
?
?Information only:
?- CPU Utilization: 0.74%
?- File I/O: 0.151 MB
?- Process Private Memory: 0 MB
```

I didn't find anything particularly suspicious. When I checked the window.performance.timing values in JS Console (in a different run through VS2012), I noticed that the app took no more than 300 ms between navigationStart to loadEventEnd.

I have tried analyzing the App_LaunchData.etl using the Windows Performance Analyzer (using it for the very first time). I noticed that the jscript9.dll was loaded after 11 seconds since the app launch. The host therefore did not give control to the user code until then. I didn't find any high CPU or I/O.

I tried repeating the WACK tests on 2 other WIN8 machines to see similar launch times. I have uploaded the app packages, the validation reports and the App_LaunchData.etl files here http://sdrv.ms/16xNvio.

What could be going wrong and what is way out?

An app we developed is blocked on WACK tests. Your heelp in resolving this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. Keep us updated if you see any authoritative responses to this issue. FWIW, I'm also seeing this behavior on the Microsoft created Winjs apps (including Mail, Calendar, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Changing the target platform to **x86** (from the default 'Any CPU') made the app start really fast. The Blank/Grid apps as well as our app passed WACK in green.

I don't yet know the reason for the sluggish start of apps on x64.